# Is James Moriarty gay, in BBC's Sherlock?

Tags: character, sherlock

In BBC's [Sherlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_(TV_series)), James Moriarty is portrayed as a criminal mastermind. He is a psychopathic individual who is obsessed with Sherlock.

Moriarty is extremely difficult to read and anticipate. He shows a carousel of emotions ranging from serenity, humour, mockery, childish, laid-back, to violence.

In S01E03, when he *meets* Sherlock, Sherlock deduces him as gay.

[image: Sherlock meets Jim]

Also, In S02E03, when he comes to meet Sherlock after his trial, the following conversation takes place between the two:

> SHERLOCK: If you could break any bank, what do you care about the highest bidder?
>
> JIM: I don’t. I just like to watch them all competing. “Daddy loves me the best!” Aren’t ordinary people adorable? Well, you know: you’ve got John. I should get myself a live-in one.

And finally, in the S04E03 when *he returns*, in the flash back:

> GOVERNOR: Mr Moriarty.
>
> JIM: “Big G.” Means “governor.” Street speak. I’m a bit down with the kids, you know? I’m relatable that way. D’you like my boys?
>
> JIM: This one’s got more stamina, but he’s less caring in the afterglow.
>
> *Source: http://arianedevere.livejournal.com*

So, is Jim really gay? Please quote evidences from the show in support of your answer.

Comment: No he dressed to distract sherlock

Comment: P.S. I am not really talking about that specific scene, rather Sherlock series as a whole. Also, I edited my question for further clarity.

Answer (score 5):

In that specific episode, Moriarty dressed that way to redirect Sherlock's attention elsewhere.

In canon (original Sir Arthur Conan Doyle books) there was no **direct** description of Moriarty's sexual orientation.

From the glimpses of behavioral patterns Jim Moriarty shows us, I would say he is not gay but... bisexual?

> ...But the flirting’s over, Sherlock ... Daddy’s had enough now! I’ve
>   shown you what I can do. I cut loose all those people, all those
>   little problems, even thirty million quid just to get you to come out
>   and play. So take this as a friendly warning, my dear. Back off. (He
>   smiles.) Although I have loved this – this little game of ours.
>   Playing Jim from I.T. Playing gay. Did you like the little touch with
>   the underwear?

He specifically said he played the gay part in their first meeting. Although he behaved like a gay person and then explained it was a mask to attract Sherlock's attention, there are other hints about Moriarty's sexual orientation.

In The Reichenbach Fall, Moriarty asks one of the guardians to slip her hand into his pants pocket and take out a gum for him: **[Warning: can be disturbing]**

> [image]

Which looks entirely based on a sexual innuendo to make people feel uneasy.

Beside these two situations, Moriarty always gives a sense of sexually manipulative personality that works for various side of gender definitions with different sexual orientations.

That leaves me defining his orientation as bisexual or omnisexual with an aromantic side.

Please note that I tried to be as gentile as I can be while defining a sexual orientation.

Comment: That video is creeping me out!

Comment: +1 Based on the TV series, I'd say you have it right: Moriarty's sexuality, such as it is, is sublimated to his obsession with manipulation and 'game playing'.